# Which is correct for future schedules, present simple, future simple or both?

Tags: grammar

Normally we use present simple with future schedules. Can we use will+inf. too? 
e.g The film ...... at seven o'clock tomorrow.
A. Starts 
B. Will start

Comment: Neither sounds wrong, but "starts" sounds significantly more natural.

Comment: We could provide a more useful answer if we had more background. In some contexts, the modal might make sense; in others, not so much. In common speech, it's _starts_ by a landslide. You can add context by using the [edit](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/101872/edit) link under the question.

Comment: There must already be an answer for this - I feel like this is one of the most common questions to come up on ELL.